# Grails - Is there a recommended way of dealing with CSRF attacks in AJAX forms?

Tags: security, grails, csrf

I am using the Synchronizer Token Pattern for standard forms (useToken = true) but I cannot find any recommended method of dealing with this over AJAX.

**EDIT**

Since posting this, I have rolled my own solution incorporating Grails existing pattern from above.

In the jQuery ajax I post the entire form (which will include Grails' injected SYNCHRONIZER_TOKEN and SYNCHRONIZER_URI hidden fields) such that the withForm closure can perform as expected in the controller.

The problem is, on successful response, there is no new token set (as the page is not reloaded and the g:form taglib is not evoked) and so I do this manually in the controller calling into the same library as the g:form taglib, and return it in the ajax response, and then reset the hidden field value. 
See below:

```
var formData = jQuery("form[name=userform]").serializeArray();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'delete',
    data: formData,
    success: function (data) {
        // do stuff
    },
    complete: function (data) {
        // Reset the token on complete
        $("#SYNCHRONIZER_TOKEN").val(data.newToken);
    }
})
```

in the Controller:

```
def delete(String selectedCommonName) {

    def messages = [:]
    withForm {
        User user = User.findByName(name)

        if (user) {
            userService.delete(user)
            messages.info = message(code: 'user.deleted.text')

        } else {
            messages.error = message(code: 'user.notdeleted.text')
        }
    }.invalidToken {
            messages.error = message(code: 'no.duplicate.submissions')
    }
    // Set a new token for CSRF protection
    messages.newToken = SynchronizerTokensHolder.store(session).generateToken(params.SYNCHRONIZER_URI)
    render messages as JSON
}
```

Can anyone identify if I have unknowingly introduced a security flaw in the above solution. It looks adequate to me but I don't like hand rolling anything to do with security.

Answer (score 1):

Nice!

IMO, you'd better reset the token at the same time.

`SynchronizerTokensHolder.store(session).resetToken(params.SYNCHRONIZER_URI)`

and if you have multiple forms in the same page, define a variable to hold tokens returned from each ajax request.

btw, why not implement the token pattern on your own?

- Generate a token, e.g., `UUID.randomUUID().toString()`, and store it into session with the url as the key.
- Check and reset the token at the satrt of post actions.

Comment: Actually, I've since revised this implementation as sending back the token for the next request meant that a would be attacker with some underlying knowledge of the Grails Synchronizer Token Pattern implementation would be able to successfully exploit it. So I kept the above implementation to prevent duplicate form submissions and enhanced it with my own session scoped solution generating my own UUID in the same way as you mention above.

Comment: I see. Maybe you should think about resetting the token in `complete` rather than `success`. In my project, there's tons of ajax resquests in the same page, so I append and reset the token in ajaxSend and ajaxStop globally.

Comment: Yes, good point on doing it in *complete* rather than *success*. For my own implementation, I generate the token and add to the session as soon as you hit the controller. I don't see the advantage of continuously regenerating, it's unlikely someone is going to guess it in any reasonable period. Obviously once the user leaves and returns to the page, a new one is generated again.