# CSRF Guard on Grails AJAX request

Tags: ajax, grails, csrf, csrf-protection, owasp

I am having a hard time making CSRF Guard to work on Ajax Requests in my Grails Application. I already added the Javascript Servlet in the page and followed instructions in their website. The problem is that it kept on saying that I have missing token. Aside from that, our Ajax request is not inside a form which I would assume that CSRF would look for forms and auto-inject the token for Ajax POST requests. I just merely get each parameters and pass it as data in my Ajax POST request.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with the pattern outlined by the author of this question [Grails - Is there a recommended way of dealing with CSRF attacks in AJAX forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30368038/grails-is-there-a-recommended-way-of-dealing-with-csrf-attacks-in-ajax-forms)