# Ignore a URL CSRF Guard

Tags: jquery, grails, csrf, owasp, zap

I have applied CSRF Guard in my Grails Application. However in my Login page, I have an import of jquery-1.10.2.min.js library:

```
<g:javascript library="jquery-1.10.2.min" />
```

But when I ran OWASP Zap to scan my application, it keeps on getting an alert: Anti CSRF Tokens Scanner on the URL: http://localhost:8080/MyApp/js/jquery-1.10.min.js

Is there a way for CSRF to ignore this URL and just marked it as protected or is there any other way to get this ignored or pass in OWASP Zap scan.

Thanks!

Comment: Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30368038/grails-is-there-a-recommended-way-of-dealing-with-csrf-attacks-in-ajax-forms)

Answer (score 0):

I've just started work on a ZAP add-on that will allow you to automatically change the risk levels associated with alerts.
This will allow you to flag specific alerts as false-positives.

More details here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/zaproxy-develop/S81DferznW8/nSFSMDN-BwAJ

Cheers,

Simon

Comment: Hi @Psiinon actually I really don't want ZAP to just ignore it but to pass the scan. I was kind of thinking about a code change somewhere or configuration.

Comment: You can exclude that URL from the whole scan.
Or if its a false positive raise an issue giving full details and we'll look into it :)