# CSRF in grails, withForm{}.invalidToken{} not working fine

Tags: security, grails, csrf

As I've to use csrf in my grails application, I'm doing it by encapsulating my action logic under `withForm{...}.invalidToken{....}`, also I'm adding an attribute as:  `g:formRemote useToken="true"` under `g:formRemote` tag in gsp.

The problem is, I'm always getting inside the `invalidToken{...}` block on submit and hence my form is not getting saved.

How should I make it working properly?

Example:

```
def action = {

       withForm{

             ......
  }.invalidToken{

          println "Invalid Token code"    

    }


}
```

gsp ex:

```
<g:formRemote useToken="true" ...>
     ...
     ...
 </g:formRemote>
```

Comment: Please add [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

`useToken` is not supported with `formRemote`. Please take a look on https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/2.5.x/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/taglib/JavascriptTagLib.groovy#L349

The supported attributes for `formRemote` are:

```
     * @attr name REQUIRED The form name
     * @attr url REQUIRED The url to submit to as either a map (containing values for the controller, action, id, and params) or a URL string
     * @attr action The action to execute as a fallback, defaults to the url if non specified
     * @attr update Either a map containing the elements to update for 'success' or 'failure' states, or a string with the element to update in which cause failure events would be ignored
     * @attr before The javascript function to call before the remote function call
     * @attr after The javascript function to call after the remote function call
     * @attr asynchronous Whether to do the call asynchronously or not (defaults to true)
     * @attr method The method to use the execute the call (defaults to "post")
```

With that said. You can keep using the `withForm` in your controller and implement the form submission using jQuery or other JS library and send the token. Please take a look at this question: [Grails - Is there a recommended way of dealing with CSRF attacks in AJAX forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30368038/grails-is-there-a-recommended-way-of-dealing-with-csrf-attacks-in-ajax-forms)

Also I would recommend you to move on from tags like `formRemote`. I'm assuming you're using at least Grails 2.x. In case you want to migrate to Grails 3.x in the future, the Ajax-related tags are deprecated.

Hope this helps.