# Prevent CSRF attack in grails?

Tags: java, grails, csrf, response-headers

I work on grails 2.2.1. I have gone through many links with respect to CSRF to implement in my project.

[Grails 3 CSRF protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36072320/grails-3-csrf-protection)

[Grails - Is there a recommended way of dealing with CSRF attacks in AJAX forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30368038/grails-is-there-a-recommended-way-of-dealing-with-csrf-attacks-in-ajax-forms)

http://www.redtoad.ca/ataylor/2011/01/grails-cross-site-request-forgeries-csrf/

The above are few of the many links I've gone through.

Now, coming back to my question. I don't want to use "withform" or ".invalidtoken".

I want to use RequestHeaderFilter.groovy file which is already there. I want to use the request header to validate the origin header.

Please find the code snippet below.

```
class ResponseHeaderFilters {
    def filters = {
        all(controller: '*', action: '*') {
            before = {

                def serverURL = grailsApplication.config.grails.serverURL ?: "http://localhost"
                //this could/should be improved upon if serverURL is not set in one of our config files
                //def OriginPrefix = serverURL.replace("http", "https")
                def requestOrigin = request.getHeader('Origin')

                if (request.getHeader('X-Requested-With')?.equals('XMLHttpRequest')) {

                    if (requestOrigin && requestOrigin == serverURL) {
                        response.setHeader('Expires', '-1')
                        response.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
                        response.addHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store')
                        response.setHeader('X-UA-Compatible', 'IE=edge')
                    } else {
                        return false
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        addNoCachingHeaders(uri: '/**') {
            after = {
                response.setHeader('Expires', '-1')
                response.addHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
                response.addHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store')
                response.setHeader('X-UA-Compatible', 'IE=edge')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This piece of code doesn't work as expected. The page in the UI goes blank when ever I click on anything.
Last I checked the "Origin" is coming as null.
Can anybody help me with this issue?

Answer (score -2):

In Grails 3.x you need to use an Interceptor instead of a Filter, but the functionality is the same.

```
class ResponseHeaderInterceptor {

    boolean before() { true }

    boolean after() { true }

    void afterView() {
        // no-op
    }
}
```

I'll leave the implementation up to you, but do see the docs for more information: http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#interceptors

Comment: True. My bad. :)